# Javascript - Count first element of multi dimensional array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have below code to extract the ID and username of a unique list of authors.

```
    let authorsList = await Poem.find({ 'author.id': {$nin: community.busAdmins}}).where('communities').equals(community._id).populate('authors').sort({"author.username": 1});

    let uniqueAuthorsList = [];
    authorsList.forEach(details => {
        if(!uniqueAuthorsList.some(code => code.username == details.author.username)){
            uniqueAuthorsList.push({username: details.author.username, id: details.author.id});
        }
    });
```

For each of those authors, I want to count how many blogs they have written. So far I have this code:

```
const counts = {};
        uniqueAuthorsList.forEach((el) => {
        counts[el] = counts[el] ? (counts[el] += 1) : 1;
        });
        console.log(counts);
```

But this only returns:

```
{ '[object Object]': 7 }
```

How can I count the records using only the first element of the array (username), so I can return a list like this?

```
Dave: 4
Emily: 7
Mark: 2
```

Comment: Try: counts[el.username] = counts[el.username] ? (counts[el.username] + 1) : 1;

Comment: Use `+ 1` not `+= 1`. You're already assigning to the element, you don't need to use an assignment operator when adding.

Comment: Why don't you just do this in the `uniqueAuthorsList` object itself in the first loop? Add a `count:` property to each object. Initialize it to `1` when you're adding a new object, otherwise increment it in an `else` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the counts in `uniqueAuthorsList` when you're creating it.

```
let uniqueAuthorsList = [];
authorsList.forEach(details => {
  let author = uniqueAuthorsList.find(code => code.username == details.author.username);
  if (author) {
    author.count++;
  } else {
    uniqueAuthorsList.push({
      username: details.author.username,
      id: details.author.id,
      count: 1
    });
  }
});
```

You might want to just make `uniqueAuthors` an object rather than an array.

```
let uniqueAuthors = {};
authorsList.forEach(details => {
  if (uniqueAuthors[details.author.username]) {
    uniqueAuthors[details.author.username].count++;
  } else {
    uniqueAuthors[details.author.username] = {
      username: details.author.username,
      id: details.author.id,
      count: 1
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: Just by the nouns (Poem.find, authors), I think the OP is actually looking to reduce the poems array into an author-keyed object (and count the values).

Comment: @danh Good point, `uniqueAuthorsList` could more usefully be an object instead of an array.